# comtrade importing data error No data matches your query or your query is too complex. Request JSON or XML format for more information

Tags: r, api

I work to aliment a Data warehouse of world trading, using the API of comTrade.Un.org to extract data with R langage like this :

```
 > str <- paste("http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?freq=M&fmt=csv&ps=",j,"&r=",i,"&p=",k,"&cc=AG6&rg=1",sep ="")
 > download.file(str, paste("import",j,"de",i,"avec",k,".csv"), method = "auto", quiet = FALSE) # pour csv
```

j : is the year for example 2016.
 i : the ISO code of countries that i want to have information.
 k : the ISO code of countries that export to the country i.

but some csv files are not correctly downloaded and i don't know why or how to fix that .
the csv file contains this :

> No data matches your query or your query is too complex. Request JSON or XML format for more information.

Please any explication aboute this error and how to get the csv files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you must check if the data is available for all countries in Comtrade website by listing the trading of all countries ,then run my script for each country in the list obtained.
Also if the data is too large , you have to get an account form comtrade (129$,690$ or 6000$ in the average ) to have the access to data.